# Is there any easy way to Handle this scenario?

Tags: java, xml

I am looking for a simpler solution.

There a **tool A**

It will process the XML of below format

```
<xml>
     <subtag1></subtag1>
         <subtag1A></subtag1A>
     <subtag2></subtag2>
     <subtag3></subtag3>
</xml>
```

There a **tool B**

It will process the XML of below format

```
<xml>
     <subtag1></subtag1>
         <toolBsubtag1A></toolBsubtag1A>
     <subtag2></subtag2>
     <toolBsubtag3></toolBsubtag3>
</xml>
```

I have to process both the XML is same Tool.

XML wise the difference is only few tag names.

In java i could parse this and use a logic to differentiate it.

But is there any easy way to do this? Is there any parser to do this? Is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You get the xml and need to feed it into both tools, which accept the different formats you show? Or you have the tools which create the xml, but slightly different?

Comment: Hi @daniu, I have to supply xml to both the tools. The only difference will be tag names. Now I want both tool the process both the xml. I need simpler way to read the XML with minimal code change

Answer (score 0):

You can create class `Tool` and parse the xml into it. The empty tags will be null

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Tool {
    String subtag1;
    String subtag2;
    String subtag3;
    String subtag1A;
    String toolBsubtag1A;

    @XmlElement
    public void setSubtag1(String tag) {
        this.subtag1 = tag;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setSubtag1A(String tag) {
        this.subtag1A = tag;
    }

    //...
}

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Tool.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Tool tool = (Tool)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("C:\\file.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract JAXB-class and create the correct subtype when it comes to actually create the XML.

Something like

```
@XmlRootElement(name="xml")
abstract class AbstractData {
    // add properties with common element names here
    @XmlElement(name="subtag1")
    private String subtag1;
    public void setSubtag1(String setTo) { subtag1 = setTo; }
    public String getSubtag1() { return subtag1; }

    // and keep the others abstract
    public abstract void setSubtag1a(String setTo);
    public abstract String getSubtag1a();
}
```

then create subclasses for the appropriate tools

```
public class ToolAData extends AbstractData {
    @XmlElement(name="subtag1A")
    private String subtag1a;
    public void setSubtag1a(String setTo) { subtag1a = setTo; }
    public String getSubtag1a() { return subtag1a; }
}
```

and

```
public class ToolBData extends AbstractData {
    @XmlElement(name="toolBsubtag1A")
    private String subtag1;
    public void setSubtag1(String setTo) { subtag1 = setTo; }
    public String getSubtag1() { return subtag1; }
}
```

Then, when you create the output data, just create the proper subclass.

```
AbstractData data = toolA ? new ToolAData() : new ToolBData();
data.setSubtag1("subtag1data");
data.setSubtab1a("subtag1adata");
```

And marshal to the file.